# Is there a file size limit to move a file over SFTP once processed by camel?

Tags: apache-camel, sftp

A file size of 9MB works as expected. But a file of 15MB does not get moved.

I am using:

```
sftp://{{sftp.user}}@{{sftp.server}}/?username={{user}}?password={{sftp.pass}}&binary=true&passiveMode=true&move=processed/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [`localWorkDirectory` option of the Camel FTP component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html#_using_local_work_directory). This downloads the files to the configured directory first.

```
sftp://{{sftp.user}}@{{sftp.server}}/?username={{user}}?password={{sftp.pass}}&binary=true&passiveMode=true&move=processed/&localWorkDirectory=/tmp
```